# adding pixel tracker in Gmail?

Tags: google-analytics, gmail, analytics

i am looking for an open source (preferred solution) or commercial way to include a pixel tracker in my gmail emails. nothing particularly complicated, I just want to know if you opened my last email or not ;-)

Many thanks!

Comment: There is a [good article](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/06/17/email-tracking-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1373045793) on using the Measurement Protocol along with MailChimp to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mail:

```
< img src="http://mydomain.com/mypixel.gif" alt="">
```

On the servers command line

```
grep mypixel.gif path/to/access.log
```

Provided you use an apache server and the logfile is called access.log (should be the default). Look at the [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) manpage for options and exact syntax, but it doesn't get much less complicated or more open source than that (it might be that your tracking efforts are thwarted by the Gmail image proxy, though).

Comment: thank you so much! but your answer is too technical for me :) I know the basic idea of pixel tracking: when the pixel tag A is downloaded from your server you know that mail A has been opened. I have a personal website, but I do not know if I have an apache server.. I do not even know what I should do in that case.. can you please give more details so that I understand what to do? many thanks!!

Comment: I may have a PHP MySQL server